# How do I hide my Scripts folder?

Tags: permissions, ftp, chmod

I have a directory on my website specifically for javascript files, I want these javascript files to be hidden, so if I type the url to it it says Forbidden or disallows access, but my front-end website files can still access them to execute them when needed. Is there a way to do this through a FTP client?

Cheers,
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this trough a ftp client. It is the task of your webserver to forbid access to certain files.

If you change permission, the webserver won't have access to them anymore, so this is not the way to go.

You must configure your webserver to restrict the access. If you're using Apache, you can use an `.htaccess` file. There's different ways of doing this, many depends on the way the webserver is configured.

The easiest is to put an `.htaccess` file in your Scripts folder which contain only this none line :

```
deny from all
```

However, like peeter said, there's a good chance this will break your site, since the browser must access theses files, so you can't restrict access.

Comment: there's no way to hide it from view, but keep through-script access to it? I purchased a javascript library for my project and I wish to disallow view of it to protect my purchase. At the moment anyone can use a web developer toolbar to copy/paste the code

Comment: Javascript is executed client side, so the browser must have access to it. If the browser has access, anyone has access, since the browser is a client like any other.

Answer (score 1):

Put a htaccess file in your scripts folder containing `deny from all`, but this will stop your pages from accessing the scripts also (though not if you pass them through the PHP engine first)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to hide JavaScript files that are executed on the clients side. If a client(browser) cannot access the files means non of your javascript code is executed.

If I understood your question correctly then you cannot achieve what you're trying to achieve.